# Contunious model update

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka

Hello I have a trained model on credit card fraud detection, however I want to find a solution so I can update the model parameters with new input records to simulate the pattern changes, is there any repository or ideas to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is called [online machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) or [incremental learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning). check which is closest to your thoughts. It is not applicable to all algorithms and all tools to not implement it. You might find adjusting your model to an online/incremental structure makes it weaker on your metrics. Also evaluate retraining your model with newer information. Maybe you can retrain it every day/week/month and get better results.